# Why won't my innerHTML change upon PHP echo?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a program that gets an input from an HTML input field

```
   <form method>
   <input name="filmslike" id="input">
   </form>
```

Then it goes through a javascript file that gets an ajax response from a PHP file

```
let div2Change = document.getElementById("div2Change");
let input = document.getElementById("input");
input.addEventListener("change", getTable);

function getTable(){
    let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("GET", "filmslike.php");
    ajax.send();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
            alert("in if");
            array = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
            str = "<table class='table'>";
            for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                str += "<tr><td>" + array[i] + "</td></tr>";
            }
            str += "<table>";
            div2Change.innerHTML = str; 
        }
    }
    
}
```

the PHP file gives back an array from a database

```
require "DatabaseAdaptor.php";    // This includes class DatabaseAdaptor as if it where above this code.

$theDBA = new DatabaseAdaptor();  // constructor a DatabaseAdaptor object.

$moviesLike = $_GET['filmslike'];

$array = $theDBA->getAllMoviesLike($moviesLike);

echo json_encode($array);
```

and the database function returns items that are similar to $part

```
    public function getAllMoviesLike($part) {
        $stmt = $this->DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE name like '%" . $part . "%'");
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

I don't understand why I'm not getting any change to my innerHTML. The alert says that it goes into the if statement (though it only activates inconsistently). I tried to use POST instead of GET, and it didn't work. What is wrong?

Comment: I replaced your "java" tag with "javascript", which seems to have been what you intended.  I can't see that this question relates to Java in any way.

Comment: It will be better to replace `alert("in if")` with `alert(ajax.responseText)` so you will see to output of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You don't send anything to the server for searching from AJAX. You need to add input value to the request:

```js
ajax.open("GET", "filmslike.php?filmslike="+document.getElementById("input").value);
ajax.send();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. So I changed this and tweaked some things, and what I've gotten now is that the alert shows that I'm successfully getting back the correct PHP echos, but that once it is taken by the JSON.parse and put into variable array, the items become "object Object". I looked this up and the general sentiment seems to be the problem is turning things into strings, but I'm supposed to use json_encode/json_parse for this program, and I've used it before with arrays and it has worked. I can't understand the problem here.